# OpenCV2 Fourcc Codec for Web Playback

Tags: python, html, opencv, video, html5-video

I'm looking for an OpenCV fourcc codec that can be used in `cv2.VideoWriter` which allows the video to be played back through a HTML file. I've tried, `*'DIVX'` and `*mp4v` through `cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc`, but both don't seem to work in the following HTML file:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src=<FILE PATH> type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

NOTE: When I say they "don't work", I mean that the video element is there, but I cannot play the video i.e. no frames are loaded into the video element

I'm also looking for a codec that doesn't need external installations and works just with cv2

Answer (score 0):

Browser support for video containers and codecs is diverse. You can hope to get support for the ["WebM" container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebM) (based on matroska) and its specified codecs.

Most browsers also support MP4 with H.264 video, so you can try "AVC1" as fourcc with a ".mp4" extension.

"DIVX" is certainly unlikely to be supported. "mp4v" may or may not work (doesn't necessarily imply H.264).

All of that requires OpenCV to have been built with some actual media library (ffmpeg is common). OpenCV natively only supports MJPEG inside an AVI container.

Comment: AVC1 requires installation of h264 modules though

Comment: as I said, producing *any* browser-compatible video will require OpenCV to have been built with a suitable video backend, such as ffmpeg. building OpenCV with ffmpeg is rather standard. the `opencv-python` module on the python package index fits the requirements.

Comment: I am using OpenCV with ffmpeg. But the h264.dll still has to be installed, which I'm trying to avoid

Comment: there is no "h264.dll" to be "installed". ffmpeg was either built with libx264 or it wasn't. either way, I believe my answer answers your question. I can't help it if browsers expect certain formats and codecs. I can only state the facts.

Comment: If it wasn't, are there any alternatives? Becuase, my buid wasn't built with libx264

Comment: `pip install opencv-python` should come with ffmpeg that contains libx264, or some fallback library such as openh264. or you can build OpenCV yourself. I would recommend WebM and suitable codec anyway. H.264 isn't the most compatible codec for browsers.